# ¿Como no salirse del rago de una tabla en excel?

Tags: excel, tablas

Buen día:
tengo la siguiente tabla:
[image: Tabla de trabajo]

En la columna[D] quiero poner una fórmula como esta:

```
=([Sem01] [D]-[Sem01] [NB]-[Sem01] [D]-[Sem01] [RP]+[celda en otra tabla]
```

¡Parece una tontería! ¿Verdad?
El objetivo es usarla mediante DESREF([D];[OtraCelda];0)
Siendo el valor de [OtraCelda] negativo, que me sume, por ejemplo la fila de encima.
Hasta ahí he llegado, pero cuando la celda es la primera del rango la cosa se des...compone, es decir no funciona.
Ya llevo varios días intentando mil cosas y no doy con ello, en otros tiempos lo sabía hacer, por eso sé que se puede, pero de eso han pasado varias décadas.

**¿Hay alguien por ahí que recuerde o sepa como demonios se hace con funciones?**
Ya que el libro lo estoy usando en un curso de desempleados y los ordenadores (computadoras) eso de las macros lo llevan muy, pero que muy mal.
De antemano Mil Gracias.

[P.S.] Como pueden ver la funcionalidad contraria si pude hacerla, columna [NNL_LT]

Answer (score 0):

Buen día:
Me auto respondo (a medias).
Encontré que `=SI.ERROR((G6+H6+J6-F6);Demanda)` funciona, pero...
Sigo teniendo `G6, H6, J6, F6` y si muevo la tabla de descujiringa la condenada.
Y no puedo convertir esas referencias a referencias de tabla.